# Encountering Issues with Prometheus Basic Auth

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, basic-authentication

I am a beginner with Prometheus and recently encountered some issues while configuring Basic_Auth.

I deployed a Prometheus instance with Basic_Auth locally. What's strange is that I am able to use the Prometheus Web UI with the username and password that I set. However, the targets in scrape_configs return a 401 error.

P.S. I'm encountering the same issue while using the remote_write feature of Prometheus Agent.

Here's the error message I'm getting:
`caller=scrape.go:1317 level=debug component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=prometheus target=http://localhost:9090/metrics msg="Scrape failed" err="server returned HTTP status 401 Unauthorized"`

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my configuration:
Prometheus 2.44.0
prometheus.yml:

`- job_name: "prometheus" scheme: http basic_auth: username: prometheus1 password: bcrypt_password static_configs: - targets: ["localhost:9090"]`

Answer (score 0):

In the `scrape_config`, the password is **not** bcrypted:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "prometheus"
    scheme: http
    basic_auth:
      username: admin
      password: {password} # Not bcrypt'ed
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - "localhost:9090"
```